# javaで変数の計算をすると「精度が失われる可能性があるintからshortへの変換」が出る

Tags: java

javaで変数計算をしていると下のようなエラーが出ました

***エラーメッセージ***

```
精度が失われる可能性があるintからshortへの変換
short c =a+b
```

***ファイルの内容***

```
byte a = 64;
short b = 100;
short c =a+b
```

どこで変数がintになったのですか？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[java](/questions/tagged/java) の仕様として `+` 等、二項演算子の処理の際には `short` `byte` では演算されず `int` に暗黙の型変換がなされる (これは [c](/questions/tagged/c) の仕様を引き継いでるんでしょう) ので
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2
`byte + short` の結果は `int` になります。

似たような例が挙げられていますね
https://www.javadrive.jp/start/cast/index5.html

Answer (score 0):

intになったのは`a+b`の計算結果です。

以下も同じエラーが出るはずです。

```
b = b + b;
b = b + 1;
b = b + 0;
```

乱暴にいうと、char、byte、shortなどintよりサイズの小さい整数の計算の結果はintになるようです。詳しくは774RRさんの回答を参考にしてください。